# Generators in python

Tags: python, generator, yield

I just came across the problem that I could not use the built-in `range()` function of python for float values. So I decided to use a float-range function that I manually defined:

```
def float_range(start, stop, step):
    r = start
    while r < stop:
        yield r
        r += step
```

Problem is: This function returns a generator object. Now I needed this range for a plot:

```
ax.hist(some_vals, bins=(float_range(some_start, some_stop, some_step)), normed=False)
```

This will not work due to the return type of float_range(), which is a generator, and this is not accepted by the hist() function. Is there any workaround for me except not using yield?

Comment: Why is not using `yield` a "workaround"?  What did you hope to gain by using `yield`?

Comment: What does `bins` expect? An integer? or a range?

Comment: yield is the standard solution for defining a default range function.

Comment: @Christian an int OR range

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to give a range, you can do either

```
ax.hist(some_vals, bins=(list(float_range(some_start, some_stop, some_step))), normed=False)
```

Or just make your `float_range` return a list:

```
def float_range(start, stop, step):
    result = []
    r = start
    while r < stop:
        result.append(r)
        r += step
    return result
```

BTW: nice reference on what you can do with generators in Python: https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators

Comment: that list()-thing is what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a generator to a list using:

```
list(float_range(1, 4, 0.1))
```

But seeing you are using matplotlib, you should be using numpy's solution instead:

```
np.arange(1, 4, 1, dtype=np.float64)
```

or:

```
np.linspace(start, stop, (start-stop)/step)
```

Comment: but with np.arange I could not get any float values to work, like `np.arange(0.2, 0.8, 0.05)`

Comment: NumPy's solution is [`linspace`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html). It is specifically warned that using [`arange`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) for non-integer steps is a bad idea in the documentation.

Comment: @ZerO you can force it to give you floats.

Comment: @user2357112 using arange with floats may lead to numerical inaccuracies, and so not give you exactly what you want; but the OP will have the same problem with the proposed approach. Using one or the other depends on what do you want to ensure are correct: distance or number of elements. For the bins of a plot, probably either would work fine.